# Cancelling out square roots gives 2?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, arithmetic, irrational-numbers, rational-numbers

**Question**:

> If $$N = \frac{\sqrt{\sqrt{5}+2}+\sqrt{\sqrt{5}-2}}{\sqrt{\sqrt{5}+1}}$$Find N <sup>(This is a subset of a larger question)</sup>

---

**My approach**:

After rationalizing the denominator, by multiplying fraction with $\frac{\sqrt{\sqrt{5}+1}}{\sqrt{\sqrt{5}+1}}$, I got:

$$\frac{(\sqrt{\sqrt{5}+2}+\sqrt{\sqrt{5}-2})*\sqrt{\sqrt{5}+1}}{\sqrt{5}+1}$$

Which is leading me nowhere. The textbook has simply asserted that $$N^2 = 2$$ <sup>(Substituting the large fraction with $N$ to save space)</sup>

I squared the numerator and got: $$2\sqrt{5}*2*(\sqrt{\sqrt{5}+2}*\sqrt{\sqrt{5}-2})$$

---

**My Question**:

1. How would I further go with this to solve for $N$? or what would be the correct/easier way to find $N$ ?
2. How would I know when to rationalize denominators, and when to square the fractions, to get the answer ?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$N^2 = \frac{(\sqrt5 + 2) + (\sqrt 5 - 2) + 2\sqrt{(\sqrt 5 + 2)(\sqrt 5 - 2)}}{\sqrt 5 + 1} =\\=\frac{2\sqrt 5 + 2\sqrt{5-4}}{\sqrt 5 + 1} =...$$
Can you see where this is going?

Comment: Yes, I can ! Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Squaring the  fraction gives

$$\frac{2\sqrt5+2\sqrt{\underbrace{(\sqrt{5}+2)(\sqrt5-2)}_{=1}}}{\sqrt5+1}=\frac{2\sqrt5+2}{\sqrt5+1}=2$$

Comment: Thank you! Nice visual representation !

Comment: You're welcome.

Comment: Also, please answer the second part of my question.

Comment: @GaurangTandon The second part has no real answer. You know because you have done several similar calculations and because you try out several things, one of them then leads you to the right answer.

Comment: Since there's nested roots and To get rid of one root  the best idea is to square @GaurangTandon

Comment: @SamiBenRomdhane Ok, thanks.

Comment: @5xum Thanks for that.

Answer (score 1):

The next step would be to combine the square roots, $$\sqrt{\sqrt5 - 2} * \sqrt{\sqrt5 + 2} = \sqrt{(\sqrt5 - 2)(\sqrt5 + 2)}$$ Hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: I think a much more elegant way to go about this problem would be to capitalize on the convenient algebraic properties of the golden ratio. Start by converting all the roots of 5 to expressions involbing $\phi$ instead: e.g., $\phi=\frac{\sqrt{5}+1}{2}\implies \sqrt{5}+2=2\phi+1$, and so forth.

Comment: What is golden ratio? And what is that symbol? I am sorry but I can't understand it. Thanks though :)

Comment: @GaurangTandon Oops, I guess my hint won't help you much if you don't know what it is! You should look it up though, since it's just one of those special numbers from elementary geometry like $\pi$ and $\sqrt 2$ that you are expected to be familiar with after a certain point. I refer you to the wiki: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Golden_ratio

Comment: Ok, thanks. I will try and study more hard and learn this too :)